# Use get_option in an IF statement in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, key

I'm trying to activate a functions written in php whenver a checkbox is checked. The checkbox leaves an empty option in de database, when enable it shows

```
my-general-options with value: 
a:1:{s:13:"my-custom-option-1";s:1:"1";}
```

Therefore the options page is working correctly right?

The code I'm using is:

```
      if ( get_option('my-custom-option-1') === '1')  {   
        echo 'hello world</div>';
      }
```

Also tried:

```
      if ( get_option('my-general-options', my-custom-option-1') === '1')  {      
        echo 'hello world</div>';
      }
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [WordPress `get_option()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/), use the `option_name` *(not the `option_value`)*.

[image]

So if your `option_name` is for example "this-is-my-option-key", use it as follows:

```php
$option_value = get_option('this-is-my-option-key');

if ( isset( $option_value['my-custom-option-1']) && $option_value['my-custom-option-1'] == 1 ) {
    echo '<div>' . __('hello world') . '</div>';
}
```

It should work.